# Flutter engine Destroy issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-add-to-app

I have added flutter into the existing android app.using prewarm flutter engine.

```
var flutterEngine = FlutterEngineCache.getInstance().get(Constants.FLUTTER_ENGINE)

        if (flutterEngine == null) {
            flutterEngine = FlutterEngine(this)
            FlutterEngineCache.getInstance().put(Constants.FLUTTER_ENGINE, flutterEngine)
            flutterEngine.navigationChannel.setInitialRoute(
                "route1"
            )
            flutterEngine.dartExecutor.executeDartEntrypoint(
                DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint.createDefault()
            )
        }
```

When I destroying the flutter engine         `FlutterEngineCache.getInstance().get(Constants.FLUTTER_ENGINE)?.destroy()`
I am getting the following error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot execute operation because FlutterJNI is not attached to native.

  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot execute operation because FlutterJNI is not attached to native.
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.ensureAttachedToNative(FlutterJNI.java:222)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.onSurfaceDestroyed(FlutterJNI.java:315)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.renderer.FlutterRenderer.stopRenderingToSurface(FlutterRenderer.java:207)
        at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView.detachFromFlutterEngine(FlutterView.java:795)
        at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onDestroyView(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:442)
        at
```